# Looking for pattern to combine partial classes from different assembly's

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am having the following problem. I have a main project, and some extra projects that have similar functionality.

For example: I have an MVC website, then a class library project "A" with a "SettingsHelper". This just defines static wrappers for configuration settings so they can be used as propertys.

Then I have another class library project "B", which **also** contains a "SettingsHelper class".

How can I merge these SettingsHelpers in my main project, so I can use: SettingsHelper.Property from both modular extra projects.

I would like to be able to plug extra class libraries into one project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Sounds pretty much like Dependency Injection.  Normally you would expose SettingsHelper as an interface (your contract), and program against that.  Then a DI container, such as Ninject, StructureMap, or Windsor would plug an implementation of that interface into the relevant parts of your code based on configuration.</strike>

This would allow you to code against a known contract and provide different libraries depending on the circumstances, the DI framework could then use that library to get the concrete implementation of the interface.

Would you need both instances at the same time?

Note that you cannot utilise the `partial` keyword across different assemblies, only within an assembly.

**Update:** based on your comment it sounds like you want to do something like Composition.  Have a class that takes both classes from either library and combines them into one class that can be used by your application.  Whether you then configure it to do something special or load the types when the libraries are present, it can all be encapsulated in this new class.

**Update 2:** alternatively, look into MEF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: same comment as above. Yes I do need both instances at the same time. Dependency injection will not work because the static class only defines propertys like: CampaignId, Version, IsTesting .... those property's depend on the module (class library) I implement. Interfaces are then useless, unless I make a function and decouple the 'strongly typed' propertys

Comment: Interfaces aren't useless for properties... but they are useless for your static classes.

Comment: yes, as I said: interfaces are *then* useless, implying the previous reference to my classes beeing static.

Comment: MEF: seems to be exactly what I need. Can you maybe pull that into a new answer so I can vote it up and mark it as the correct answer. Also your update was pretty much exactly what I was looking for. The only problem I am having is that I don't won't the project to be configured to use the plugins, rather than the plugins be configured to hook into a project :) actually is IoC, but dependecy injection is wrongly reffered to the kind of IoC I need.

Comment: That sort of backwards IoC is a little misleading.  The project they are landing in is going to still need to be structured to accept plugins.  Instead of writing a new answer, I'll strike out the stuff you didn't need.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work. Partial classes cannot be divided over assemblies -- they don't exist in the CLR, only in the editor and the compiler. So they are compiled together into a single CLR class.

What you can do, is inherit one from the other. However, helpers tend to be static classes, so that won't work either.

The other alternative is not to write helper classes, but extension methods. You can extend classes in one assembly with methods defined in another assembly (or multiple other assemblies). See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx.

Comment: I know I can't use partials. I was looking at the same functionality. I can't use inheritance, because that would make the classes dependant, and I want them to be pluggable. Extension method might work. I'll check that out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Was thinking about it, but extensions are useless, what I have now is some classes, spread into different projects that define property's. I want to be able to acces those propertys in one main class depending on the class library projects I import... (stringly typed offcourse ;) )

Comment: You're thinking of mixins, but the CLR doesn't support them and hence neither does C#. You'll have to compromise...

Comment: I hate compropis :), but allready feared this. I am thinking about other ways to achieve this,by T4 scaffolding in nuget packages ...

Comment: I would say It is able with @Adam's solution

Answer (score 1):

There is a way; Visual Studio allows the same code file to be included in more than one project.

When you do “Add”/”Existing Item” to can select a file that is in the different folder.

This is what some of the silver light support does so as to allow a “common class” that has some method that are only on the server and one methods that are only on the client.

(As to the question of “good design” you will have to decide that yourself, a lot of people don’t like having the same class compiled in different ways in different projects.   Think if the mess you could get in with #if XXX, when XXX is only defined in one of the projects)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that move **both Helper** classes in **3rd project** and add reference of **that** project to both of your projects. So this new library will become **shared datastructures and functionalities library**.

Regards.

Comment: This way, again you start creating dependency's. I want to Decouple them. NOT couple them

Comment: At this point, if you are talking about "pluggability", may define this 2 separate Helpers in HelperA and HelperB assemblies, that define common interface IHelper, and in mainproject load them dynamically ( I mean LoadAssembly). What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

The specific pattern you are after is called a [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Unfortunately you are not going to get any help from the compiler getting this right. Essentially:

1. Create a new `CombinedSettingsHelper` class in your local assembly.
2. If the two `SettingsHelper` types are in the same namespace you will need to set up aliases for them (check the reference properties in the solution explorer, and [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this).
3. Implement the object so that it can access both `SettingsHelper` objects.

To clean up your facade you might try having a abstract method along the lines of `abstract object GetSettingValue(string name);`. Your facade could then inherit from the same base class and call these on its contained children. For example:

```
public abstract class SettingsHelperBase { public object GetSettingValue(string settingName); }

// Assembly1
public class SettingsHelper : SettingsHelperBase { }

// Assembly2
public class SettingsHelper : SettingsHelperBase { }

public class SettingsHelper : SettingsHelperBase
{
    private List<SettingsHelperBase> _backends = new List<SettingsHelperBase>();

    public readonly PropertiesImpl Properties;
    public class PropertiesImpl
    {
        private SettingsHelper _settingsHelper;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)_settingsHelper.GetSettingValue("Name");
            }
        }

        internal PropertiesImpl(SettingsHelper helper)
        {
            _settingsHelper = helper;
        }
    }

    public SettingsHelper()
    {
        _backends.Add(asm1::MyNs.SettingsHelper);
        _backends.Add(asm2::MyNs.SettingsHelper);
        Properties = new PropertiesImpl(this);
    }

    protected override object GetSettingValue(string settingName)
    {
        foreach (var item in _backends)
        {
            var val = item.GetSettingValue(settingName);
            if (val != null)
                return val;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you describe was also an approach I was thinking of, but it is pretty useless, because I create the wrapper functions in the "settingshelper" so I can use intellisense to prevend mistakes, and I don't want a class to define which settinghelpers I want to use, I want the different "settingshelper" to "inject" themselfs into my main Project. which MEF seems to do. Also I do not 100% agree with the façade term on this approach :) but that's another discussion